# How to replace multiple strings in PHP using str_replace?

Tags: php

Hi guys I have an error with my code.
I am trying to use the str_replace() function to remove the string I don't need. But I don't get my expected result. Here's my code:

Here's my sample data:

```
clip_sample_data.mp4
clip_sample_data.ogg
clip_sample_data.webm
```

Here's my function:

```
$video_data = array(
            'mp4_title'     =>  isset($columns['mp4_title']) ? str_replace(".mp4", "", pathFileNameExploder($columns['mp4_title'])) : '',
            'ogg_title'     =>  isset($columns['ogg_title']) ? str_replace(".ogg", "", pathFileNameExploder($columns['ogg_title'])) : '',
            'webM_title'    =>  isset($columns['webM_title']) ? str_replace(".webm", "", pathFileNameExploder($columns['webM_title'])) : '',
            'clip_mp4'      =>  isset($columns['clip_mp4_title']) ? str_replace(array(".mp4", ""), array("clip_", ""), pathFileNameExploder($columns['clip_mp4_title'])) : '',
            'clip_ogg'      =>  isset($columns['clip_ogg_title']) ? str_replace(array(".ogg", ""), array("clip_", ""), pathFileNameExploder($columns['clip_ogg_title'])) : '',
            'clip_webm'     =>  isset($columns['clip_webm_title']) ? str_replace(array(".mp4", ""), array("clip_", ""), pathFileNameExploder($columns['clip_webm_title'])) : '',
        );
```

In replacing the .mp4, .ogg, .webm I have no problem.
But in replacing the clip_ together with the .mp4, etc etc has an incorrect result.

```
clip_sample_data_2clip_
```

Comment: You can use rtrim function it will work fine. .   http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_rtrim.asp

Comment: @AnilBaweja [`rtrim`](http://php.net/RTRIM) trims a set of characters, not a specific string.

Comment: @  Alexander O'Mara   You can remove anything using this. .

Comment: i think  ) is not closed for clip_

Comment: @AnilBaweja If you do `rtrim('testing.ogg', '.ogg');`, you will get `'testin'`, not `'testing'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are misunderstanding how to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to replace multiple strings. The first argument is an array of string you want to replace, and the second is another array of matching strings to replace them with.

You probably intended to do something like this.

```
str_replace(array(".mp4", "clip_"), array("", ""), "clip_sample_data.mp4")
```

Which will return the following string.

```
"sample_data"
```

And since you want to replace everything with just a blank string, this code can be reduced to this.

```
str_replace(array(".mp4", "clip_"), "", "clip_sample_data.mp4")
```